# ViewController doesn't load background image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, viewcontroller

This question isn't a basic typo or something. As it works, when normally transitioning.

However, to end my SKScene I have an `@protocol` to let its parent view controller know the game has ended. Once that happens, it runs this code.

```
[skView presentScene:nil];

UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
//
ConnectionsViewController *game = [storybord instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ConnectionsViewController"];
//
[self presentViewController:game animated:NO completion:nil];
```

This, works and switches `ViewController` however, it loads the `viewcontroller` with no background image. Or at least, displayed background image. Which I'm finding relatively strange, the animations run on the `viewDidLoad:` but the image does not display. Then, if activate any of the `IBActions` the background image will load then transition. And sometimes, it will load after a few seconds. But rarely.

What I can see is white, that is all.. And cannot for the life of me figure it out.

Steps that lead to this problem.

Disconnecting from a **Multipeer session**->**removing the SKView**->**modal to different viewcontroller**->**no background image**.

I've also checked for memory leaks and none are apparent.

Comment: have you tried this `[self presentViewController:game animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Yes, when trying that it refuses to believe it's in the window heir-achy. This `@protocol` method of doing it is sketchy.

Comment: How are you setting the background image? Does the image exist in the bundle? Does the name you used *exactly* match the image name? Is there another view that might be covering the background? Is there enough available memory to load and render the image? Can you load the image and set it in code? If not, do you get any useful errors? More details, please.

Comment: @Caleb The image is set in an imageview which is allocated. The image exists, and works fine when the modal is done normally. Nothing else is covering the background, the UIButtons load however, the background does not. And appears white. Is there a technique to debug whether the background is or isn't loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what was causing the issue, however. spreading out the collateral of code that is executed over a dispatched period of time has fixed the errors. I can only imagine it was because so much was going on.